# How to change value in subscription? using rxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

im creating a timer, and need your help
im just learning angular & rxJS and i have some question about this

Im creating a timer which have start,stop,pause,reset

and btn reset must 'pause' my timer to 300ms

how to do it? :D

my start timer fnc

```
startTimer() {
    this.intervalStream$ = interval(1000);
    this.sub = this.intervalStream$
        .subscribe((value) => {
          this.subscribeTimer = this.convertSeconds(this.timeLeft - value);
          this.currentTime = this.timeLeft - value;
        });
  }
```

and after this start i have

```
pause() {}
```

can't understand how to do it :D

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to stop the observable at 300ms even tho your observable emit an event every second?

Comment: I want achieve that: if im click 'pause' my timer wait 300-1000 ms and started again

Comment: So you want the stop method to delay the emitted values by 300ms ?

Comment: Yeap, i cant realize it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an timer with stop resume and pause https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq9zvk.

Your variables

```
isstop = new Subject();
  ispause = new Subject();
  private time = 0;
  isRunning = true;
  timer: Observable<number>;
  timerObserver: PartialObserver<number>;
```

This set timer put in in onInit or connect to click start function

```
this.timer = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ispause),
        takeUntil(this.isstop)
      );

    this.timerObserver = {
      next: (_: number) => {  
          this.time += 1;        
      }
    };


    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
```

and these are stop resume and pause functions

```
goOn() {
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
  }
  pauseClick() {
    this.ispause.next();
    this.isRunning = false;

  }

  stopClick() {
    this.time = 0;
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.isstop.next();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a that what im find)
Im find a method to make 'PAUSE' on 1s, and after automatically start timer)

Comment: It is easy also u just need to put     setTimeout(() => this.goOn(), 1000) in my example in pause fucntion i edited stackblitz check it